# Prevent .NET Core 3.0 from building an EXE file by default

Tags: .net, command-line-interface, .net-core-3.0

With .NET Core 3.0, a little feature was added to the build process.  According to Microsoft:

> .NET Core now builds framework-dependent executables by default. This behavior is new for applications that use a globally installed version of .NET Core.

I have searched, but I cannot find a way to prevent this.  Unfortunately, this executable causes me issues when pushing my application to Cloud Foundry because it now thinks it's a stand-alone EXE file when it should run it with dotnet cli using the DLL file built for my application.

Is there a way to prevent this default EXE from being built?

I can always add a final step to my build process to remove it, but it seems like there should be a way to prevent it in the first place.

Comment: Hi BrianM.  The `UseAppHost` property can be set to false (e.g. `/p:UseAppHost=false` on the command line) and that will disable the creation of the executable.

Comment: @PeterHuene is right. As an alternative to a command line change, you can also set `<UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>` in the .csproj's `<PropertyGroup>` as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

@PeterHuene and @vcsjones answered the question perfectly in their comments above:

> The `UseAppHost` property can be set to false (e.g. `/p:UseAppHost=false` on the command line) and that will disable the creation of the executable.

- Peter Huene Oct 21 '19 at 18:21 [from comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491492/prevent-net-core-3-0-from-building-an-exe-file-by-default#comment103314144_58491492)

or

> As an alternative to a command line change, you can also set `<UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>` in the .csproj's `<PropertyGroup>` as well.

- vcsjones Oct 21 '19 at 18:25 [from comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491492/prevent-net-core-3-0-from-building-an-exe-file-by-default#comment103314253_58491492)

Comment: FYI this answer was the subject of a [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402394/2288578).